# how to set an list<unknown type> to an list<object>

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a big problem, I have a function. this function has 1 parameter of Object type, so I can receive a simple object or a list of an unknown type.

in case my object parameter be a list, I need to set his values to `List<object>`. and I don't know how to do it.

for example:

```
var m_list = new List<String>(){"a","b","c"};
MyFunction(m_list);
```

the function

```
private void MyFunction(Object parameter){
    List<Object> myObjectsList= new List<Object>;//I need set the values of parameter to this object
}
```

Comment: The real question is why would pass a list into a method as an `object` just to cast the object to a `List<Object>`?  Change the parameter to an `IList` at a minimum; you could probably get away with `IEnumerable`

Comment: any reason why you want to use "object"? defeats the purpose of generics in a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface (or `ICollection` or `IList`):

```
var sequence = (IEnumerable)parameter;
```

You can then loop over the items directly without generics, or use LINQ to copy them to a `List<object>`.

```
myObjectsList =m_list.Cast<object>().ToList()
```